# Router changes its MAC Addresses

Tags: router, dd-wrt, mac-address

I constantly lose my Internet connection. After analyzing the problem I found that my router, TL-WR741ND [TP-Link], changes its MAC address by switching through the WLAN's, LAN's and WAN's 
MAC addresses.

If I clone the MAC address of the router's WAN to the one I want, it doesn't change automatically. Probably a bug.

I am using DD-WRT v24-sp2 so I should be able to change something in the OS.

How do I set a MAC address to the device and make sure it doesn't change its MAC on the WAN port?

Comment: Telling us what router it is and what firmware version would really help.

Comment: Router - TL-WR741ND [TP-Link]. Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2